# C# connecting (referencing) couple *.cs files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, reference

I have couple questions about referencing methods / variables between two or more *.cs files. I know that there are similar topics, but I still don't quite understand what is going on.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015.

So here is the problem. I have 2 files, those files are First.cs and Second.cs. They are saved in completely different, known locations on hard disc.

Inside First.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Forum
{
    class First
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        public int GiveMeNumber()
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside Second.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Forum
{
    class Second
    {

        int number = // method from file First.cs

    }
}
```

How do I access method GiveMeNumber() from First.cs in Second.cs as assignment for int number? How do I tell my compiler where are those files?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: For visual-studio, you need to assign them in same solution, if they are in different project, you need to add reference too.  In fact, I don't understand your true question, you want to load it dynamically? reflection? or...??

Comment: I found thath when I'm making Windows Forms Aplications. I usually copy and paste same parts of code. By splitting it to separate scripts I can aces those methods more easly and what more important, I can just change methods in one file rather than in every Form manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Alex said in his comment.

You can create a solution/project, add existing item, and browse to your first.cs and second.cs.
Mark both files with the public-keyword

for example:

```
namespace Forum
{
   public class Second
   {
       int number = // method from file First.cs
   }
}
```

Then both class can be used within each other.
So you could do

```
var first = new First();
var number = first.GiveMeNumber();
```

you probably want to do it the other way around, because I think you have a console app where your First class has a main-method.

does that help>?

Comment: Actually it is working. Thanks for clearing things out. I was trying this before but I always get some stupid results. Thanks.

Comment: How do I do the same, but with Windows Forms?